# Initializing class dictionary with dict comprehension - scoping

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, static-members, dictionary-comprehension

Let's say I'm writing a class that does something that takes a lot of time.

```
class Example:
    def expensive(self, arg):
        return arg + 1
```

Since it takes a lot of time, there are few possible arguments and every result will be used many times, I decide to precompute the results when the application is started:

```
class Example:
    def expensive(arg):
        return arg + 1

    EXPENSIVE = {
        0: expensive(0),
        1: expensive(1),
        2: expensive(2),
        # ...
    }

    del expensive
```

**Note that this does work**. Obviously, this is very repetetive, so I decide to use dictionary comprehension:

```
class Example:
    def expensive(arg):
        return arg + 1

    EXPENSIVE = {x: expensive(x) for x in range(3)}

    del expensive
```

Unfortunately, Python [rejects this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzknsbhYwbUiMbcgJ9WKSwEIUlLTFFIrClLzijPLUjUSi9I1IeIgUJRaUlqUpwAUVNBWMOQCi7tGBLj6BXuGuSrYKlRXWCHprdBUSMsvUqhQyMxTKErMS0/VMNas5YJakoNQ@P8/AA) with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 1, in <module>
    class Example:
  File ".code.tio", line 5, in Example
    EXPENSIVE = {x: expensive(x) for x in range(3)}
  File ".code.tio", line 5, in <dictcomp>
    EXPENSIVE = {x: expensive(x) for x in range(3)}
NameError: name 'expensive' is not defined
```

To be honest, this really surprised me. Python's scoping rules were really intuitive to me so far. Why does this happen, and how can I work around it?

Comment: `self.expensive()` ? also you need to have `def expensive(self, arg):`

Comment: @zimdero Try it. I dare you. While I find the stackoverflow question that explains this. You need `self` for a method, but not for an internal static function.

Comment: Precomputing the results may lead to doing unused computations. What you want to avoid is recomputing the same thing twice. You could use functools.lru_cache or implement your own caching decorator.

Comment: @NieDzejkob and where is your `staticmethod` decorator ?

Comment: The error code appears misleading. The error is caused when you call "del expensive", which isn't a defined term.

Comment: @Ghoti remove the line, error stays.

Comment: Sorry. It seems that I redefined the function outside of the class and it persisted in memory after being commented out.

Comment: @zimdero I want to access `expensive` only from the inside of the class, [and staticmethod works for the exactly opposite use case](https://tio.run/##TY5BC4JAEIXv/ooHXpJC1G5C0GUPXiIIouuiYwmuK7ObGNFv38zC9t3mfd8M0z/sTXdb58pWGgMxStW3lAeYsjdW2qZUNCkVQjApPRCsRt2MIGbNs1dRDRp76kwz0EryNfruf8Jk79xhKrFGGsy9uBzF4VScBXZ4LmaSe0eSaLOA1AepBzIfZB4IEcfxPL2C34ftX3XuDQ).

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I am aware of that, but I'd rather compute everything beforehand rather than compute it when a fast response is more important, since I can guarantee that each result will be used many times during the execution.